# FactoryGirl won't initialize factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Consider the example:

```
*# spec/factory/sections.rb*

FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :any_section do
        (...)
    end


    factory :fake_section do
        (...)
    end


    factory :section do
        (...)
    end
end
```

I found that my rspec tests can only see the `:section` factory. All the others ends up throwing an error like: `uninitialized constant FakeSection`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that FactoryGirl does not see the `any_section` and `fake_section` factories, it is that you are not specifying their classes, so it is guessing the names (i.e. `any_section` becomes `AnySection` and `fake_section` becomes `FakeSection`).

To fix the problem just specify that the class is `Section` using the `class` option:

```
factory :any_section, :class => Section do
    (...)
end


factory :fake_section, :class => Section do
    (...)
end
```

See also [this article](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/2011/05/factory-girl-custom-class-name/).